# Fetch records based on timestamp and not day Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, time

So i have a field that has a date on it  formatted

`mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS`

I want to select records that are before a certain time.  So mm/dd/yyyy is not considered only timestamp.

so i want to

```
select * from table where datefield < 5:00am
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help.

```
select * from table where  to_number(to_char( timestamp, 'HH24' )) < 5
```

Comment: thanks this solved it.  the comparison string wasn't quoted when i first tried it :)

you can add to_number(...) if you'd wish to compare with numbers

Comment: @Eat A Peach but user told it worked...what error are you getting

Comment: No didn't got the chance to test as it is a day off but I have used these concepts many tines..what wrong are you seeing in the query

Comment: If time part is 07:00:00, then your query will be comparing `'07:00' < '5:00am'`, which will be true. I would compare the numbers here, instead of varchar.

Answer (score 2):

There are many functions to work with dates/timestamps in oracle.
Here is an example of 'extract':

```
select extract(hour from d), extract(minute from d) 
from
(select systimestamp as d from dual)

EXTRACT(HOURFROMD) EXTRACT(MINUTEFROMD)
------------------ --------------------
                14                   52
```

And just in case, there is a have artillery of TO_CHAR, TO_NUMBER, TO_DATE functions

```
TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(yourdate, 'HH24')) < 5
```

Also, it is not clear from your question what type of column you have
if it is date/timestamp than my answer above should work for you.
if it is VARCHAR2 or similar, you have a choice:
1. convert to date using TO_DATE(yourdate, 'your format')
2. use string functions like SUBSTRING to manually separate hours and minutes.